# Исправьте ошибку с вводом данных в список от пользователя

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я протестировал свою программу  с заранее заготовленными данными как в примере и все работает нормально, но эти данные должен вводить пользователь,как исправить вторую строчку чтобы пользователь мог делать ввод? просто у меня показывает ошибку

```
a = [input().split()]
s = [input().split() for _ in range(a[0])]
sumch=0
poz=[]

for i in range(a[0]):
  string = (''.join(s[i].split())).split('=')
  e = eval(string[0])
  sumch += e
  if e != int(string[1]):
     poz.append(i+1)

if poz: 
  print (a[1] - sumch); print (*poz)
else: 
  print (0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы хотите получить набор целых чисел, то превратите строку в числа, например

```
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

это касательно вашей 1 строчки:

```
a = [input().split()]
```

в таком виде ваша строка - это СПИСОК СПИСКА - ведь `.split()` уже делает список

если бы вы написали:

```
a = input().split()
```

то получили бы список строк, но вам нужны числа, а значит надо:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Касательно основного кода - вы зря использовали `eval` - там это не нужно

```
  string = (''.join(s[i].split())).split('=')
  e = eval(string[0])
  sumch += e
  if e != int(string[1]):
     poz.append(i+1)
```

А нужно разбить строку и вычленить числа, например так:

```
parts = text.split()

price = int(parts[0])
amount = int(parts[1][1:]) # отрезан первый символ '*'
cost = int(parts[2][1:])   # отрезан первый символ '='

#выполнить проверку
if price * amount != cost:
```

полный код:

```
# получить кол-во товаров в чеке и итоговую сумму
items_count, items_cost = list(map(int, input().split()))

# проанализировать корректность товаров в чеке
errors = []

for index in range(items_count):
    # получить запись чека и разбить ее на части
    parts = input().split()

    # сформировать информацию о товаре (стоимость, кол-во и цену)
    price = int(parts[0])
    amount = int(parts[1][1:]) # отрезан первый символ '*'
    cost = int(parts[2][1:])   # отрезан первый символ '='

    # вычесть из итоговой суммы сумму товара
    items_cost -= price * amount

    # проверить запись чека на корректность и в случае ошибки - записать позицию товара в чеке
    if price * amount != cost:
        errors.append(index + 1)

# вывести результат
print(items_cost)

if errors != []:
    print(*errors, sep=' ')
```

Comment: я хочу чтобы ответ в такой форме был записан `a=[3, 2300]
s=['99 *2 =199', '20 *100 =2000', '11 *4 =55']`

Comment: да вы вообще зря `eval` делали - сейчас допишу

Comment: если вам не трудно, не могли бы вы написать как это будет выглядеть в исходном варианте пожалуйста

Comment: марат, того, что я написал достаточно, чтобы сложить 2 и 2 и получить нужный код, но так и быть - держите